# i am getting error on getting the ID here

Tags: spfx, react

```
RetrieveSPData(){   
 var reactHandler = this;    
     jquery.ajax({    
         url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('items')/items?$select=ID',
         type: "GET",    
         headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},    
         success: function(resultData) { 
           console.log(resultData);
        var ID = [resultData.d.ID];



           reactHandler.setState({ 


             items: resultData.d.results,

           });  

         },    
         error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {    
         }    
     });

    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Is your list name - "items" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a REST query as below

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Id,Title
```

it will return an object obj.d.results (results is an array)

[image]